# Using a variable as a prefix argument to a format directive

Tags: format, common-lisp

I need to print something with variable number of spaces before it. For example if I need to print 5 spaces before my text, I will do:

```
(format T "%5T My Text")
Output:     My Text
```

In place of 5, can I use a variable and be able to pass on a value to it? What I am looking for is like:

```
(format T "%(~d)T My Text" 5)
output:     My Text
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
(format T "~vT My Text" 5)
```

See [22.3 Formatted Output](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm):

> In place of a prefix parameter to a directive, `V` (or `v`) can be used.
>   In this case, **format** takes an argument from *args* as a parameter to the
>   directive. The argument should be an *integer* or *character*. If the *arg*
>   used by a `V` parameter is **nil**, the effect is as if the parameter had
>   been omitted. `#` can be used in place of a prefix parameter; it
>   represents the number of *args* remaining to be processed. When used
>   within a recursive format, in the context of `~?` or `~{`, the `#` prefix
>   parameter represents the number of *format arguments* remaining within
>   the recursive call.